# how could I repalce Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2] back to r

Tags: manipulate, symbolic

do a calculation in mathematica

```
r = Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]

D[D[E^(I (-k r + t \[Omega]))/r, x], y]
```

but how could I get back to repalce Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2] back to r

the result is:
$$
-\frac{k^2 x y e^{i \left(t \omega -k \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)}}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}}+\frac{3 i k x y e^{i \left(t \omega -k \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)}}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^2}+\frac{3 x y e^{i \left(t \omega -k \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)}}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{5/2}}
$$

Answer (score 4):

This will produce a simplified form:

```
 Simplify[
 D[D[E^(I (-k r + t \[Omega]))/r, x], y] /. 
  Power[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, n_] :> Power[HoldForm[r], 2 n]]
```

[image]

Comment: a elegant solution,

rule is ok, why you use delayed

     Simplify[
     D[D[E^(I (-k r + t \[Omega]))/r, x], y] /. 
     Power[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, n_] -> Power[HoldForm[r], 2 n]]

Answer (score 2):

Use rules to do both the forwards and the backwards substitutions.

Step 1:

```
deriv = D[D[E^(I*((-k)*r + t \[Omega]))/r /. r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], x], y]
```

Step 2:

```
PowerExpand[deriv /. {x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -> r^2}]
```

Comment: It's not work and input should be t*\[Omega]

Comment: after @ubpdqn and @ Stephen,
step2 can be change to: PowerExpand[% /. {x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -> HoldForm[r]^2}]  and this is work
[result_image](http://i.imgur.com/vYLjf3d.png)

Comment: I fixed the `\[Omega]`, and I added a temporary variable `deriv` to ensure that step 2 picks up the output of step 1 - i.e. the `%` that I originally used in step 2 will not work correctly, unless you evaluate step 2 immediately after step 1.

Comment: Thank you, when I use your answer, I have define the r, so I have to use the HoldForm, in fact, your's answser is a direct answer.
Thank you very much.
[result](http://i.imgur.com/AiIXzb1.png)

Answer (score 2):

Another way using the built-in coordinate transforms :

define a rule to perform the transformation :

```
rule = Rule[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, 
          Simplify[TransformedField["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", 
                   x^2 + y^2 + z^2, {x, y, z} -> {\[Rho], \[Theta], \[Phi]}], 
                   Assumptions -> {\[Rho] > 0}]]

expr = D[D[E^(I (-k r + t \[Omega]))/r, x], y]

Simplify[expr /. rule, Assumptions -> {\[Rho] > 0}]
(* (E^(-I k \[Rho] + I t \[Omega]) x y (3 + 3 I k \[Rho] - k^2 \[Rho]^2))/[Rho]^5 *)
```

Comment: this is more physical, thank you very much!